# how to control auto scroll in scrollview with slider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an a vertical scroll-view in which i have 3-4 child scrollviews that slide horizontally, i want to control the vertical scroll-view (Parent) with a slider.

Anyone have any idea for this?

Thanks
Inam

Comment: You want to add another control to do what's the scroll view is already capable of doing? Could you explain?

Comment: I know poor explanation from me :( I have a vertical slider when i slide it then i want it to scroll the scroll-view simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Scroll_View scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,460, 320, 460) animated:NO];
```

Comment: Please refrain from linking to your blog in every answer you provide.  This is considered to be spam here.

Comment: Please add some explanation.